# Efficient Union Find with Existential Quantifier?

Tags: algorithm, prolog, union-find

Is there a classical algorithm to solve the following problem.
Assume the union find algorithm without existential quantifiers
has the following input:

```
x1 = y1 /\ .. /\ xn = yn
```

It will then build some datastructure u, so that I can check
u.root(x)==u.root(y), to decide whether x and y are in the same
subgraph.

The input can be characterized by the following grammar:

```
Input :== Var = Var | Input /\ Input
```

Assume now we also allow existential quantifiers:

```
Input :== Var = Var | Input /\ Input | exists Var Input
```

What union find algorithm could deal with such an input.
I am still assuming that the algorithm builds some datastructure
u, where I can check via u.root(x)==u.root(y) whether x and
y are in the same subgraph.

Additionally u.root(x) should throw an exception when used 
with a bound variable. These variables should all have been 
eliminated and not anymore part of datastructure. Means
the subgraph should have been accordingly reduced, without
changing the validity of the result.

Bye

Comment: This seems interesting, but I don't understand what you want. What does it mean for a node to be existentially quantified? What does it mean for a result to be "valid"? What really is this all about (ie what's the context?)

Comment: What is the real context though? And doesn't that just mean that you want to connect everything that points to, say, `x` to instead point to `parent[x]` and mark `x` deleted? (trivial but stupid solution: apply path-compression to everything, if that's sort of what you want then I can explain an improvement to that)

Comment: Are you asking how one can eliminate the ecistential quantifier without peaking at the internals of the DS? My gut tells me that will require O(n) for searching all possibilities, or storing an auxillary DB that will be modified at each union operation (but that makes the problem uninteresting, because it is almost identical to looking at the internals of the original DS).

Comment: parent[x] in a tunnel can't happen because it would already have been removed, removing the root on the other hand.. I'm going to put my vote on "you can't do it this way"

Comment: Then it is simple - there exists x!=y such that u.root(x) = u.root(y) if and only if u.root(x) is of height larger than 1. Or did I misunderstood what your existential quantifier is seeking?

Comment: Supposing you have `exists h (a1=h /\ ... /\ an=h /\ stuff not involving h)`, you can hoist the stuff not involving h outside the quantifier.  Then the inside is just asking for `a1=a2 /\ a1=a3 /\ ... /\ a1=an`; it doesn't involve h, so the quantifier can be dropped.  I don't see the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of an algorithm. It will traverse the AST, and
feed a special union find algorithm. First the traversal:

```
 traverse((X = Y)) :- add_conn(X, Y).
 traverse(exists(X,I)) :- push_var(X), traverse(I), pop_var_remove_conn(X).
 traverse((A /\ B)) :- traverse(A), traverse(B).
```

The special union find algorithm works with a list. This list defines
the weight of the nodes, the head of list has weight 0, the second element
weight 1, etc... add_conn(X,Y) first computes X'=root(X) and Y'=root(Y). The
less weighted of X' and Y' is connected to the more weighted one.

push_var(X) adds X to the front of the list. Making it the less weighted
node. pop_var_remove_conn(X) removes X again from the list, and removes a 
possibly established connection from X to some other node as well.